# Linux IP resolution issue

Tags: dns, dhcp, resolution, resolv.conf

I uploaded a new Ubuntu based MISP virtual machine on my VMWare ESX.
Configured it to use DHCP and IP address 192.168.10.6 was assigned to it.

I am able to get the dashboard of the MISP application from my laptop (browser) with:
http://192.168.10.6/dashboard.

but whenever I try to navigate to a link within the application (e.g **ShowFeeds**) my URL gets re-routed to 
http://127.0.0.1/showfeeds.

Every link within the application gets re-routed to 127.0.0.1. Is there any configuration that I can do within the `resolv.conf` file to fix this?

Comment: It's quite clear - the OP hasn't yet configured their VM instance. Voting to reopen. @slm

Comment: @roaima - vote to reopen if you disagree or if you can improve the situation then please edit it. But IMO plus the others that voted to close it's unclear.

Answer (score 6):

This is a configuration value within your web application. Nothing else will be able to fix it, and particularly not `/etc/resolv.conf`.

See https://github.com/MISP/MISP/issues/2983, which notes

1. Make sure you set the baseurl up correctly:

   ```
   /var/www/MISP/app/Console/cake Baseurl http://192.168.1.2
   ```
2. The VMs are hardcoded for an IP address, normally a fresh installation uses relative pathing (baseurl = "")